# cant find source-Layer Ids after reading Vector Tile using vector-tile JS library

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, vector-tiles

I took a vector tile to read the Layer and its corresponding features.

I found

My layer is "Landuse"
I found all the features that are inside the "Landuse" Layer.
I know that some of the features belong to Cemetry, Education etc..

The problem is , i am not able to find the ID of each feature like its been represented in the StyleSheet.

With out the "id", i cannot cannot seperate and display my features with in "landuse" layer

Here is one sample from the style sheet

```
 "id": "landuse_cemetery",
            "source": "orgVector",
            "source-layer": "landuse",
            "type": "fill",
            "minzoom": 11
```

My question is how to get the "id" along with features?

Please help me if i am missing some thing while reading the MVT tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing vector tile layers and style layers.

Your vector tiles contain a layer called `landuse`.

Your style can contain layers called whatever they want. In this case your style layer is called `landuse_cemetery`, but you could call it something else. The link between your style layer and the vector tile layer is this:

```
        "source-layer": "landuse",
```

If you want your cemetery layer to only include cemeteries, you probably want to add a further filter, which make use of other attributes in the data.

You can use [Vector Inspector](https://stevage.github.io/vector-inspector/) to better understand what those are.

Comment: Thank you so much Steve. Yes, i got confused with ID. But now its clear with your explanation.
One more question i have is..
Can i go with MapBox "vector-tile-js" library to read MVT tiles ?
Because i dont see any commits from past 2 years.

Comment: You should ask a separate question.

Comment: Sure. Will do that